# Console log the state data when using ngrx for State Management in Angular

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

Can anyone suggest how to console log the state when using ngrx for state management in angular application. I have gone through ngrx-store-logger but the documentation is not clear as how to create meta-reducers and use this library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with a meta reducer, as shown in the [NgRx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/reducers/index.ts#L47)

```
export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
  return (state: State, action: any): any => {
    const result = reducer(state, action);
    console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
    console.log('prev state', state);
    console.log('action', action);
    console.log('next state', result);
    console.groupEnd();

    return result;
  };
}

/**
 * By default, @ngrx/store uses combineReducers with the reducer map to compose
 * the root meta-reducer. To add more meta-reducers, provide an array of meta-reducers
 * that will be composed to form the root meta-reducer.
 */
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production
  ? [logger, storeFreeze]
  : [];
```